# ASP.Net mvc website not deployed properly on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to deploy a website from Visual Studio 2012, but it does not seem to work properly whenever I deploy it to my local IIS server using "Publish" from the projects context menu. However, when I build and deploy it to IIS express using "CTRL+F5", it builds and works fine.

First of all, it copies only some of the images. The only difference is that the image not being displayed is a background image defined like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        background-image: url('~/Images/bg.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

whereas the images being displayed are defined like this:

```
<img src="~/Images/smallLogo.png"/>
```

I've verified that all images has the same properties, and they're all in the same folder in my project. For the sake of testing this, I've set the properties to "Build Action: Resource" and "Copy to output directory: Copy always".

Now, for the second part of my problem. When I deploy it to my IIS server, it displays my first page, which in this case is a login page, just fine (except from the background image). But, whenever I try to login I just get a 404 message. I should note that the login method is doing a call to a remote service, which is included as a reference in my project. Again, it works fine when I 'deploy' it using "CTRL+F5", like in the case above.

I'm sensing that I'm missing a crucial setting here somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For some reason, the css needs to ommit the "~" character in the url-string. 
Changed it from this:

```
...
background-image: url('~/Images/bg.jpg');
...
```

to this:

```
...
background-image: url('/Images/bg.jpg');
...
```

As for the second issue, it was a somewhat similar problem. For some reason, my local iis express server accepts links not containing the "~" character. Whenever I publish it to a iis server, it does not accept this. Changed all my links / forms accordingly.